# One-direction reverse polarity protection for two possible power sources

Tags: circuit-design

I am designing a circuit that has two possible ways to receive 20V DC power, either from USB power delivery, or from a screw terminal.

When the board is powered via USB power delivery (`USB_PD_20V`) at up to 3 A, I would like the screw terminal to act as an output for the 20V.

However, when the power input is from the screw terminal, I would like to prevent any reverse current/polarity on `USB_PD_20V` (Note: `USB_PD_20V` will be at 0V when inactive).

The straightforward solution suggested seems to be a Schottky diode, but I would prefer to lower power consumption if possible. Is there a circuit that could help with this problem?
[image: Schematic]

Comment: How much leakage can you tolerate back into USB_PD_20V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 3 A, the diode solution is pretty good: a [sufficiently dimensioned Schottky diode for barely 50ct](https://www.digikey.de/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/PMEG3050EP-115/2228695) will have maybe 290 mV of drop across the diode. That means of the nominally 20 V, you still deliver 19.71 V to your load, meaning you're achieving an efficiency of 98.5 %. It might simply not be worth it optimizing any further: even with a completely lossless solution, you'd only be 1.5 % better! And you're using USB PD, which suggests your source of power isn't nearly as efficient to begin with.

However, if you really need that 1.5 %, and cost nor complexity matter too much, you would buy what is typically sold as *ideal diode*: A MOSFET with the necessary control and gate voltage generation circuitry.

Linear Technologies (now Analog Devices) used to have a lot of them. Take a look at LTC4376, which integrates the MOSFET, or LTC4412, which uses an external P-Channel MOSFET. There's also members of that family that work with N-Channel MOSFETs, but they are typically a bit more expensive because they need to integrate a charge pump power supply to generate the gate voltage which needs to be much higher than the highest voltage existing in the system.

Here's the block diagram from the LTC4412 [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc4412.pdf). In your case, you'd omit the diode on the "Auxiliary supply" and just directly connect your screw terminal:

[image: Block diagram of the LTC4412 showing gate drive, sense amplifier, control logic, histeresis and auxiliary functionality]

You can, in principle, very much build the same device from scratch; however, it's going to take quite a bit of space, and components, and also hand-tuning: The unique selling point of Analog Devices here is that you can buy an IC that has been optimized to switch reliably, at well-defined voltages, with no chance for oscillations, and no need to integrate around 20 discrete components on a board.

But the whole magic in this compared to your non-functional approaches from before is:

- use a PMOS switch for high-side switching, as NMOS would need an extra, even higher voltage source
- have an actual sense for whether the left side is higher than the right
- amplify that sensing, to a degree where it produces a sharp edge when the USB PD voltage becomes sufficiently high
- implement a gate driver that pulls the PMOS gate voltage far below the source voltage
- add hysteresis, so that you don't build an oscillator when you start drawing current from USB, in the consequence, the USB voltage slightly sags, in consequence the PMOS gets deactivated, which leads to the voltage rising again…

Comment: Thanks for the solution and clear explanation! I think I will stick to your schottky diode suggestion, especially after looking at the price of the ideal diodes..

Comment: Analog Devices certainly aren't the only one who sell such ICs. In your previous question you were pretty persistent that a diode wastes too much power, has that changed?

Comment: @MarcusMüller While the Schottky diode may sound like a great idea, it will have leakage current, and thus if you measure with a multimeter, almost 20V will appear at Type-C receptacle - and I am sure that would not be OK for a compliant or even safe USB device.

Comment: @Justme Ah, I was extrapolating from the previous question, where it was stated that the potential was pulled to 0V, so nothing was attached. Indeed, the diode I more or less randomly picked has atrocious reverse leakage! I picked an unsuitable one, definitely.

Comment: @kekpirat Justme raises an important point. What's actually attached to your USB PD port? There's gonna be some USB PD controller. Does it disconnect the port or actually keep it connected?